# C# Inline Variable Declaration failing to deploy on Appveyor

Tags: c#, appveyor

I have an appveyor project deploying a c# web api. I ran into this error:

```
File.cs(1460,52): error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'int'
```

There's many other errors listed, but all point to one thing. Inline variable declarations. Here's the code from various files that causes the error:

```c#
Guard.Requires(Uri.TryCreate($"{functionUrl}", UriKind.Absolute, out var url), "Invalid functionUrl was supplied");
```

```c#
index.TryGetValue(obj.Id, out int? parentId);
offsets.TryGetValue(obj2.Id, out double? time);
```

I looked at my build environment and noticed that it was set to VS 2015. I thought changing it to VS2017 would fix it, but it didn't.

All my projects are set to use the latest minor version of C# (7.3 at the time of writing). Inline variable declaration is a C# 7 feature, so I should be good there.

How can I get this to deploy? I feel like it's probably some obscure setting in appveyor or a csproj file I'm missing.

Comment: Which line of code gives error?

Comment: all of the lines I listed. They all have inline variable declaration at the out keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your `.csproj` indeed contains `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>`. If not, ensure that you saved project after you change language version in VS.

If this does not help try `<LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>`.

If this does not work, post a link to the build. If you consider it confidential, send it to `support@appveyor.com`.